# Как поменять тип столбца sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть 3 таблицы

1)

```
Create table Conference
(ID Int PRIMARY KEY,
Name varchar(50)
)
```

2)

```
 CREATE TABLE ConferenceEventv2(                                                 
    id INT PRIMARY KEY,                                                         
     conference_id INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Conference(ID),                             
     year INT,                                                               
      UNIQUE(conference_id, year))
    GO
```

3)

```
CREATE TABLE Paper
        (                                                             
        id INT PRIMARY KEY,                                                         
        event_id INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES ConferenceEventv2(id),                                
        title TEXT,                                                             
        accepted BIT
        )
```

Нужно посчитать отношение принятых Статей( таблица Paper) к  общему количеству для данной конференции с помощью представления, нужное число дает функция `avg()` только она не работает для bit полей, нужно как-то скастовать столбец  `accepted`  в вещественный тип, дабы не заморачиваться с громоздкими подзапросами

```
 CREATE VIEW HighPaperAcceptance 
AS 
SELECT C.name, CE.year, /*avg(accpeted)? as Acceptance_Ratio*/   as raito  From Conference as C

 join ConferenceEventv2 as CE on Ce.conference_id=C.ID
 join Paper on Ce.id = paper.event_id
 group by C.name, CE.year
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Похоже не `avg` и кастинг вам нужен, а отношение двух `count`. Пример:

```
declare @table table (conf_id int, paper_id int, accepted bit);
insert into @table values
    (1, 1, 0)
    ,(1, 2, 1)
    ,(2, 3, 0)
    ,(2, 4, 1)
    ,(2, 5, 1)
    ;

select
    conf_id,
    ratio = count(nullif(accepted, 0)) / cast(count(1) as float)
from @table
group by conf_id;
```

**upd.** хотя да, `avg` тоже работает

```
select
    conf_id,
    ratio = avg(cast(accepted as float))
from @table
group by conf_id;
```

Comment: 'avg(cast(accepted as float))' - да вот это то что нужно